Element is visible but can't click
I have an html element with data-test-id menu-btn that is visible, but the test can't click on it. It fails when trying to click. I'm trying to sort a list of cards by modified date. There's a button that has data-test-id "menu-btn". I need to click on that button to sort the cards.
Here's the code:
HTML Element:
 <sp-menu-item data-test-id="menu-btn" value="modified_date" selected="" role="menuitemradio" aria-checked="true" focusable="" tabindex="-1" id="sp-menu-item-67" dir="ltr"><!--?lit$884525023$-->Modified</sp-menu-item>

Test Code
 dateModified = () => this.page.getByTestId("menu-btn");

 await this.page.reload();
 await this.sortButton().waitFor({ state: "visible", timeout: 30000 });
 await this.sortButton().click();
 await this.dateModified().waitFor({ state: "visible", timeout: 20000 });
 await this.dateModified().click();

Here's the error:
Error: TimeoutError: locator.click: Timeout 20000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for getByTestId('menu-btn')
  locator resolved to <sp-menu-item selected dir="ltr" focusable="" tabindex="-1" ar…>…</sp-menu-item>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  performing click action

Can someone please help?

Does that button perform a navigation? The click action will also wait for that navigation.

Yes, when the button is pressed, it reloads the UI to show all cards sorted by modified data @hardkoded

Please share a [mcve] with the actual page. You can try forcing a click, but that might not be a good idea if your use case is testing rather than scraping (please state your high-level goal and provide context).

@ggorlen I provided more details

@RueVitale maybe the reload needs a little bit more of time?

@hardkoded I added more code to explain. What should I do to fix this?

The code works as is, so it's not reproducible, meaning there's nothing we can fix here. .click() already waits for visibility/actionability, so the waitFor({ state: "visible", timeout: 20000 }); is unnecessary. We'll need the actual site to be able to reproduce the problem and help. There could be many factors getting in the way: cloudflare block, arbitrary JS timing behavior, visibility/overlay, shadow DOM, iframe, etc, none of which are captured by the HTML.

Remove this line:
await this.dateModified().waitFor({ state: "visible", timeout: 20000 });

When you try to click on an item - Playwright "knows" to wait for its visibility. Try only to click on the element:
await this.dateModified().click();

You can also try to force a click:
await this.dateModified().click({force:true});

